# CMake not finding Open MPI Installed through Homebrew

Tags: cmake, openmpi, cmake-modules

I have installed Open-MPI using homebrew, using brew install open-mpi.

If I run `mpic++ main.cpp` in the command line, the code is compiled correctly. I can then run it using  `mpirun a.out`.

Now the issue is, when I create my CMakelists.txt file in Clion, it seems to not be able to find the Open-MPI package:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/4.0.2/lib")


find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)          #FAILS AT THIS LINE

set(LDFLAGS "-L/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/4.0.2/lib")
set(CPPFLAGS "-I/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/4.0.2/include")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} ${CPPFLAGS} -fopenmp")

add_executable(project main.cpp)
```

Could someone please provide guidance? I am confused as to how I can get it to work and have been trying for some amount of hours. I am new to Open-MPI.

The error it generates when I try to build:

```
CMake Error at 

/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):

Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES) Call Stack (most recent call first):   

/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)   

/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake:477 (find_package_handle_standard_args)   CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please, do not format error log as *blockquote*: this formatting doesn't preserve newlines and makes the log harder to understand. Use **code formatting** instead.

Comment: `OpenMP` is a *different* package than `OpenMPI`. Try using `find_package(MPI ...)` or   `find_package(OpenMPI ...)` instead.